# How do I say "not" using a regex when extracting a group of text?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a section of text that looks something like this:

Thing 2A blah blah Thing 2A blah blah Thing 3

Where the "3" above could actually be ANY single digit.  The code I have that doesn't work is:

```
((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s\d))
```

Since the 3 could be any single digit, I cannot simply replace the "\d" with "3".  I tried the following code, but it doesn't work either:

```
((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s\d[^A]))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

`((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s[0-9]))`

Edit: Oh I get it, you want a digit not followed by an A. Use a forward lookahead

`((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s[0-9](?!A))`

That's assuming you want it not followed by an A. Replace the A with whatever you DON'T want to follow the digit

`((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s[0-9](?![A-Za-Z]))`

Or if you know what you expect after the digit, you can add it. For example

`((Thing\s2A).+?(Thing\s[0-9][\s$])`

That will match Thing 3 followed by a space, tab, or a newline

Comment: This was a perfect solution and very thorough!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

`(((Thing\s2A).+)?(Thing\s\d))`

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want exactly...

The forward lookahead of @Falmarri might help.

If you want the last Thing followed by a digit you could use

```
 ((Thing\s2A).+(Thing\s\d))
```

(removing the ? after the + indicates it uses the default 'greedy' matching and it will eat all till the last matching Thing foolowed by a digit)

If the last thing is always the last on the line then this might help

```
((Thing\s2A).+(Thing\s\d))\s*$
```

The \s* is to throw away some remaining spaces at the end of the line.